# Is it possible to run cucumber scenarios in parallel with CucumberJS and WEbdriverIO?

Tags: webdriver-io

Is it possible to run cucumber scenarios in parallel with CucumberJS and WEbdriverIO while executing test scenarios on mobile devices?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We are executing feature files in Parallel as of now.

Running scenarios in parallel may not be possible as webdriverio and cucumber integration is using webdriverio runner.

Cheers!

Comment: Thanks very much, Raju for your reply. I want to run cucumber test cases in parallel for my mobile native app. Would you be able to share some resources or web links that can help me get started? I am trying to google but didn't find any good resource yet for cucumber with JS. Thanks.

Comment: Hi, I don't have anything for Native apps right now. I will see if I can add on GitHub.

Comment: Thanks. Appreciate your quick response :)